# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Popen' and 'str'' in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualization, ovf, ova

I'm looking at this script to disable shell=True while creating an ova.

It works when shell=True but gives me a TypeError when shell=False. 
I'm pretty sure the issue is with this part of the command - `" vi:\//" +  username + ":" + encodedPassword + "@" + hostname"` - because when I remove this element from the list (i.e. command), the script moves forward.
I've tried hardcoding values like `"vi:\//user:password@70.60.70.90"` and also removed so but I still get this type error.

Python version is 2.7

```
com1 = "/usr/bin/ovftool --acceptAllEulas --disableVerification --noSSLVerify --datastore=" + datastore +
           " --network=\"" + network + "\" --name=" + name + " " + ovalocation + " vi:\//" +  username +
          ":" + encodedPassword + "@" + hostname

#prior to disabling shell=True
# coms = subprocess.Popen(com1, shell=True,
  #                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# set shell=False - now it requires the command to be a list rather than a string.
coms = subprocess.Popen(com1.split(), shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Error:

```
'unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Popen' and 'str''
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
I know it's an issue with the vi command becuase when replace `"vi:\//" +  username + ":" + encodedPassword + "@" + hostname"` with a hardcoded `"hello"` the script moves forward.

Comment: The error message suggests that one of your variables (no idea which one) is not a string like you expect, but a `Popen` object. Perhaps add some code to print them (and maybe their `type`s) to see where you're going wrong?

Comment: Could you show us variable assignation and full traceback? Basically it means you are adding using `+` operator two objects that cannot sum up, but without knowing what are your variables, it is impossible to go further.

Comment: Could you print at least `com1.split()` before calling `subprocess.Popen()` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having trouble logging and printing stuff in this script. I need to figure out where this log is going. Something's blocking this. I'm new to these systems so unfortunately I can't do the obvious debugging prints yet.

Comment: Nah, not a duplicate. The issue there was subprocess needs a list when shell=False, but it needs a string instead when shell=True

Comment: @dozer: the accepted answer also suggest to use `shlex` which could help here.

Comment: 1) check all types of arguments, 2) build arguments as a `list` (you won't have the quoting to care about)

Comment: @SergeBallesta and vahdet - using shlex seemed to fix it. Thanks!
I'm still trying to figure out why the regular split has an issue but the shlex works fine thankfully

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a lot of argument's, it might be easier using a `string` instead of a `list of arguments` which you can do by setting `shell=True`. That's easy to debug as well, as the same command (which you should print) will run from a native shell in the same fashion.

```
coms = subprocess.Popen(com1, shell=True,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Just keep in mind, that `shell=True` might have security issues depending on how this is being run.

Comment: Problem is I need to disable shell=True. That command works with shell=True

Comment: You should print `com` to see what's going on. If you, as you said, can't print it, write it to a file. `open("myfile", 'w').write(com1)`

Comment: Thanks, will try that.